# Are there any privately owned large commercial airports?

Tags: airport, airport-operations

Do any large, commercial airports exist that aren’t owned and run by the city government they exist in/near?

To provide context, I’m talking major airports that handle commercial airline volume. Do any (hub or regional) airports exist that are fully owned and operated by private companies vs government authorities? Or is this a total fallacy? I could understand companies big enough to have their own corporate fleet/airstrip, but I’m talking a full-scale airport with airlines the public can use.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99505/discussion-on-question-by-jon-are-there-any-privately-owned-large-commercial-air).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Building an airport is a very expensive endeavor and usually involves government subsidies or is completely done by the local government. In recent decades, most government owned airports in Europe have however been transformed into companies that both own and operate the airport, usually with the government as initial owner of this company. Since this privatization, some governments have sold their shares of the company resulting in completely privately owned airports.

Going through the 20 busiest airports in Europe from [Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_busiest_airports_by_passenger_traffic#2019_half-year_statistics), the following airports are **completely or by majority privately owned**:

- London [Heathrow Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathrow_Airport) owned by [Heathrow Airport Holdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathrow_Airport_Holdings)
- London [Gatwick Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatwick_Airport) with a majority ownership by [GIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Infrastructure_Partners)
- Rome [Leonardo da Vinci-Fiumicino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_da_Vinci%E2%80%93Fiumicino_Airport) owned by [Aeroporti di Roma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroporti_di_Roma) (3.8% government owned)
- [Zürich Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurich_Airport) owned by [Flughafen Zürich AG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flughafen_Z%C3%BCrich_AG#Shareholders) (38.38% government owned)
- [Copenhagen Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Airport) owned by [Københavns Lufthavne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B8benhavns_Lufthavne) (39.2% government owned)
- [Lisbon Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisbon_Airport) owned by [Vinci SA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinci_SA), although operated by the [government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANA_Aeroportos_de_Portugal)

The following airports are run by a private company, but they are **majority government owned**:

- Paris [Charles de Gaulle Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Gaulle_Airport) and [Orly Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orly_Airport) owned by [Groupe ADP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupe_ADP) (50.6% state owned)
- [Amsterdam Airport Schiphol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Airport_Schiphol) owned by [Royal Schiphol Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schiphol_Group) (92% government owned)
- [Frankfurt Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_Airport) owned by [Fraport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraport) (51.47% government owned)
- [Madrid-Barajas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolfo_Su%C3%A1rez_Madrid%E2%80%93Barajas_Airport), [Barcelona-El Prat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona%E2%80%93El_Prat_Josep_Tarradellas_Airport) and [Palma de Majorca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palma_de_Mallorca_Airport) owned by Aena S.A. (51% owned by [ENAIRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENAIRE), which is a public corporate entity)
- [Munich Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_Airport) owned by [Flughafen München GmbH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flughafen_M%C3%BCnchen_GmbH) (100% government owned)
- [Oslo Gardermoen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Airport,_Gardermoen) owned by [Avinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avinor) (100% state owned)
- [Manchester Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Airport) owned by [Manchester Airport Holdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_Airport_Holdings) (64.5% government owned)

The following airports are **directly owned by the local governments**:

- [Istanbul Atatürk Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul_Atat%C3%BCrk_Airport)
- [Dublin Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Airport)

I am not sure who exactly owns [Sheremetyevo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheremetyevo_International_Airport) and [Domodedovo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Domodedovo_Airport) in Moscow.

Comment: Sheremetyevo is 68% (66%?) owned by TPS Avia. 30.43% is controlled by the state through the Federal Property Management Agency. I’m not sure where the missing few % have gone.

Comment: Funnily enough, even [the Russian government had troubles figuring out who owns DME](http://www.rapsinews.com/news/20141124/272639031.html), as it appears to be [privately-owned through a chain of off-shore companies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Line_Group).

Comment: @Tim Yes, but since I couldn't find details about TPS Avia I left it at that. As aland's comment shows, **It's complicated** :)

Comment: Are there any large airports that _weren't_ built by govs?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg See [Neolan's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70227/are-there-any-privately-owned-large-commercial-airports/70250#70250).

Comment: You can add London Southend Airport (Don't get me started!) which is owned by Stobart Group

Answer (score 24):

London Heathrow (LHR) is owned by a private company, [Heathrow Airport Holdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heathrow_Airport_Holdings). I'm sure there are many other examples around the world.

Answer (score 10):

The major Australian airports were all privatized from the late 1990's. Smaller regional airports are still usually council-owned and operated.

Comment: The Australian airport "privatisations" should stand as a warning to any jurisdictions hoping to solve short-term government financial problems by selling public assets, usually to favoured insiders. Our airports are now famous for monopolistic price-gouging on an extraordinary scale, while delivering substandard services to both airlines & the travelling public. The owners of YSSY have been quietly sabotaging the building of a non-curfew 2nd airport for nearly 15 years (their 1st CEO was the Prime Minister's ex Chief of Staff) , because they don't want to lose their monopoly.

Comment: @Mackk Yeah... I'm normally all for having most industries owned and run privately, but things that inherently lend themselves to monopoly - such as roads, utilities... and airports - are really a different beast. Government is almost always less efficient than private industry when free competition is allowed and feasible, but free competition on major public infrastructure projects like airports and most roads just really isn't feasible. In cases like these where a monopoly is required, having it run by people who must answer to voters is usually the least bad alternative to free market.

Comment: @reirab I suppose the way Heathrow works is there are around 6 competing airports around the region, and one especially close. Heathrow still has a number of issues - a lack of connections to the U.K. being one of them - but it’s not the Australia situation by a long stretch.

Comment: @Tim Also note that Heathrow is a hub and competes with other European hubs, like Paris, Amsterdam and Frankfurt. If Heathrow comes with incompetitive service and pricing, British Airways goes down together with it, and Air France, KLM and Lufthansa will take over the lion share of that hub traffic.

Comment: @Alexander that’s true, although the fact that Schiphol has more flights to the UK than Heathrow is annoying.

Comment: @Mackk : *"to solve short-term government financial problems by selling public assets, usually to favoured insiders"* - this is all too common. An egregious case I've heard about involves a government office, which was in a high value building in a central part of the city. To raise money, the building was sold. While debating on the building to relocate the office, they decided they would "temporarily" rent the building they were in, from their new owners, for a month or two. Practical, right? But after ten years they are still there, having payed back the selling costs 5 times over, as rent.

Comment: ...and who owns them? Can you list the top-n largest, and their owners?

Comment: @tim Note that BAA owned all the sizeable london airports --- Heathrow, Gatwick, Stansted --- and was forced in 2009 to sell them off  (sold G but appealed on S, lost 2011). e.g. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-14196639 . After that there was no point in being called BAA anymore and renamed to Heathrow.

Answer (score 6):

In New Zealand both Auckland and Wellington airports are privately owned.

In both cases the local government have a non-majority shareholding which provides a fig leaf of representation but in reality nothing other than sincecures for local politicians .

They are de-facto monopolies for the region they serve and manifest the types of behaviour you would expect from that situation. In theory their profits are limited by a formula which is overseen by national government but this just has the effect that they squeeze every last cent out of activities which fall outside of the formula but which they still have a monopoly over.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget [Punta Cana Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta_Cana_International_Airport), Dominican Republic. It was one of the first privately owned airports in the world.

Comment: @bogl Why would it not answer the question? [Punta Cana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta_Cana_International_Airport) would certainly fall under *large commercial airport* with connections to 3 continents and according to Wikipedia it is owned by "Punta Cana Resort and Club/Grupo Punta Cana".

Comment: This absolutely answers the question: yes -- Punta Cana.  A link to provide substantiation would be nice, but it's an absolutely clear & direct answer.

Comment: @bogl then edit it to remove the “don’t forget” -then it’s no-longer addressed at other answers.

Comment: So is that why the airport seems so popular, because it was built by a group that owns nearby resorts?

Comment: "Don't forget (an airport I've never heard of)"?  Links to three continents is a bit trite, practically any carribean airport links to two (N- and S- America) so just add package flights for EU tourists and you're there... with the same number of passengers as any mediterranean island airport that you'd never list as a major airport.

Answer (score 6):

Speaking of Sheremetyevo to continue @Bianfable answer, as of 23 April 2019:

- 66% are held by Sheremetyevo Holding which it turn is owned by an offshore cypriot TPS Avia Holding. TPS Avia Holding in turn: 65,22% are held by trust of Ponomaryenko abd Skorobogatko families and 34,78% Arkadiy Rotenberg. While that seems to be private owners, they are tightly connected to the Russian government and especially Vladimir Putin.
- 30,43% are off to Federal Property Management Agency
- Minorities are Aeroflot Airlines and VEB Capital (bank). Both of those companies are controlled and owned by the Russian government

So on paper Sheremetyevo is a privately owned company, but in fact it is controlled by Russian gov't.

Source in russian: [vedomosti.ru](https://www.vedomosti.ru/business/news/2019/04/23/799971-chastnie-aktsioneri-sheremetevo-mogut-prodat-30-aktsii-aeroporta)

Answer (score 4):

In the United States, there is only one privately owned and operated airport with scheduled commercial service:  [Branson, MO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branson_Airport), which only has seasonal service to three other destinations.  The vast majority of airports in the United States are at least publicly owned, and many (the majority, I believe) are publicly operated as well.

The fact that airports in the United States have largely not been privatized while many airports in Europe have been privatized is perhaps a bit surprising, given both the USA's and Europe's relative views on private vs. public enterprise.  The Government Accounting Office actually produced [a report on why airport privatization hadn't taken off](https://www.gao.gov/products/GAO-15-42) (so to speak.)